# Password validation in controller Symfony4

Tags: symfony4

I would like an advice.
I work on Symfony 4.

I need to check in my controller if the password got an uppercase letter, a number, a special character and if the length is 8 characters minimum.
I already do the checking in my twig by adding the regex in the attribute of the input.

I don't know if I must take the string and check for each letter.

Do you know a better way to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use annotations to define the validation of an entity property.

```php
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

// I assume your entity is named Users
class Users
{
    // some properties

    /*
     * @Assert\Regex(pattern = "/Your RegEx goes there/",
     *               message = "Your nice error message")
     */
    private $password;
}
```